# Scala - How to handle key not found in a Map when need to skip non-existing keys without defaults?

Tags: json, scala, collections

I have a set of Strings and using it as key values to get JValues from a Map:

```
val keys: Set[String] = Set("Metric_1", "Metric_2", "Metric_3", "Metric_4")
val logData: Map[String, JValue] = Map("Metric_1" -> JInt(0), "Metric_2" -> JInt(1), "Metric_3" -> null)
```

In the below method I'm parsing values for each metric. First getting all values, then filtering to get rid of null values and then transforming existing values to booleans.

```
val metricsMap: Map[String, Boolean] = keys
      .map(k => k -> logData(k).extractOpt[Int]).toMap
      .filter(_._2.isDefined)
      .collect {
        case (str, Some(0)) => str -> false
        case (str, Some(1)) => str -> true
      }
```

I've faced a problem when one of the `keys` is not found in the `logData` Map. So I'm geting a `java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: Metric_4`.

Here I'm using `extractOpt` to extract a value from a JSON and don't need default values. So probably `extractOrElse` will not be helpful since I only need to get values for existing keys and skip non-existing keys.

What could be a correct approach to handle a case when a key is not present in the `logData` Map?

**UPD:** I've achieved the desired result by `.map(k => k -> apiData.getOrElse(k, null).extractOpt[Int]).toMap`. However still not sure that it's the best approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That the values are JSON is a red herring--it's the missing key that's throwing the exception. There's a method called `get` which retrieves a value from a map wrapped in an Option. If we use `Int`s as the values we have:

```
val logData = Map("Metric_1" -> 1, "Metric_2" -> 0, "Metric_3" -> null)
keys.flatMap(k => logData.get(k).map(k -> _)).toMap

> Map(Metric_1 -> 1, Metric_2 -> 0, Metric_3 -> null)
```

Using `flatMap` instead of `map` means unwrap the `Some` results and drop the `None`s. Now, if we go back to your actual example, we have another layer and that flatMap will eliminate the `Metric_3 -> null` item:

```
keys.flatMap(k => logData.get(k).flatMap(_.extractOpt[Int]).map(k -> _)).toMap
```

You can also rewrite this using a `for` comprehension:

```
(for {
   k <- keys
   jv <- logData.get(k)
   v <- jv.extractOpt[Int]
 } yield k -> v).toMap
```

I used `Success` and `Failure` in place of the JSON values to avoid having to set up a shell with json4s to make an example:

```
val logData = Map("Metric_1" -> Success(1), "Metric_2" -> Success(0), "Metric_3" -> Failure(new RuntimeException()))
scala> for {
 | k <- keys
 | v <- logData.get(k)
 | r <- v.toOption
 | } yield k -> r
 res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[(String, Int)] = Set((Metric_1,1), (Metric_2,0))
```